# Reversing a circular linked list. Problem : Segmentation Fault

Tags: segmentation-fault

In the reverse function there is a segmentation fault error thrown. The reverse function is called after the first display(head);and the second display(head) could not be run due to the fault. Please check my *emphasized text*reverse() code. I have made use of double pointer.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}node;
void reverse(node **head);
node* create_list(int n);
void display(node *head);
int main(){
    cout<<"Enter the frequency of nodes: ";
    int n{0};
    cin>>n;
    node *head=create_list(n);
    display(head);
    reverse(&head);//Segmentation Fault !
    display(head);
return 0;

}

node* create_list(int n){
    node *head=NULL;
    node *p=NULL;
    node *temp=NULL;
    for(int i{0};i<n;i++){
        temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        cin>>temp->data;
        cout<<endl;
        temp->next=NULL;
        if(head==NULL){
            head=temp;
        }
        else{
            p=head;
            while(p->next!=NULL){
                p=p->next;
            }
            p->next=temp;
        }
    }
    return head;
}
void display(node *head){
    node *p=head;
    while(p!=NULL){
        cout<<p->data<<"\t";
        p=p->next;
    }
}
void reverse(node **head){//Code where segmentation fault occured is due to this function
    node *p=NULL;
    node *current=*head;
    node *temp=current->next;
    while(temp->next!=*head){
        p=temp->next;
        temp->next=current;
        current=temp;
        temp=p;
    }   
}
```

Comment: When you run this with a debugger, what is the *first* thing that this program does wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Reversing a circular linked list.

Your problem is that `create_list` *does not* actually create a circular list, it creates a "normal" single-linked list. Further, `display` assumes that the list is not circular (and would go into infinite loop if it were).

But your `reverse` function assumes that the list is circular, and will run to the end of the list and crash.

Learn to use a debugger, and [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).